# Remove rows from Pandas Dataframe which contain no numbers and no literal

Tags: python, pandas

i have a column called 'str' in a Panda Dataframe. 
As i intend to delete all rows from it which contain no numerical values [0-9]
or literal [a-z], the following statement did not work:

```
data[data['str'].str.contains(r"[a-zA-z0-9]") == True]
```

After the execution I analysed the column values. There are still values in it like:

("[[", "^")

and it deletes values (which is in this case not desired):

("1", "2016", "20160715")

Is there are anyone who could help me?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

you can use pandas dropna function it will delete that whole row which contains any null values.

df=df.dropna()

where df is your dataframe

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. There are no null values in it. I want to delete Strings like "[[", "\", "^".

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame([[']','//','.'],['a2','b2','c2'],['a3','b',']']],columns=['A','B','C'])
test = data['A']str.match('^[\w\d_-]*$')
data = data[test]
```

Output:

```
  A   B   C
1  a2  b2  c2
2  a3   b   ]
```

If you are OK with non-letter-non-number characters, I think the best way would be a dictionary of those characters followed by data.replace.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame([[']','//','.'],['a!','b2','c2'],['a3','b!',']']],columns=['A','B','C'])
df
Output:
 A   B   C
0   ]  //   .
1  a!  b2  c2
2  a3  b!   ]

remove = {'.':np.nan, '/':np.nan, ']':np.nan}  # The format is {'thing to be replaced':'new thing'}

df['A'] = df['A'].replace(remove) # Checks one column
df
Output:
    A    B   C
0  NaN  //   .
1   a!  b2  c2
2   a3  b!   ]

df.dropna()
df
Output:
  A   B   C
1  a!  b2  c2
2  a3  b!   ]
```

Make sure to replace for your specfic column. dropna() will delete any column with any NaN value.

As a cautionary, don't use Python methods such as "str" as your placeholders. Probably won't burn you here, however.

Comment: Thanks! what is the semantic behind match('^[\w\d_-]*$'). Does it exlucde only those strings which only includes special char. Because in my case a mixture of letter\numbers and special chars would be permissible. Something like '\ABC' i want to keep in that dataframe.

Comment: Thats a nice solution if you know the special chars which have to be excluded. But I was looking for a generic solution. Nonetheless, many thanks!